# How to compile the linked Silverlight Page in project

Tags: silverlight-3.0, navigation

I have two projects, one is SL navigation application and another one is a SL library which contains some SL navigation page. How could make the navigation application could find the navigation page in the other library when running?

I have tried to add the page as link item but it also cannot navigate to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the SL library as a reference in the SL navigation app?